# Azure DevOps Pipeline Archive File Without File Extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to create a zip file in an Azure DevOps pipeline.  There are three files I need in the zip archive.  One of the files does not have a file extension and Azure DevOps seems to be treating it like I specified a directory.

Here's the yaml excerpt:

```
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Add utils file to archive'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/utils'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: '$(archive.type)'
        archiveFile: '$(archive.fileName)'
        replaceExistingArchive: false
        verbose: true
```

Comment: Tested from my side, I don't have the same issue as you. I downloaded the generated compressed file locally, and the type of the file without extension is displayed as "File". 1. Please help clarify why you think "Azure DevOps seems to be treating it like I specified a directory." It would be better if you can share some screenshots. 2. What's the actual `archiveType` in your task?

Comment: Hi @Plasmana, what's the latest state of your issue? Can you let us know why you think "Azure DevOps seems to be treating it like I specified a directory" and what's the actual `archiveType` in your task, so that we can provide more help.